# How to keep html line code short?

Tags: html

Sometimes, you need many classes, other properties and maybe a couple of data attributes on a single tag.

For example something like this:

```
<div id="myId" class="class1 class2 class3" data-foo="yadda yaddd" data-bar="more yadda yadda>
    ...
</div>
```

And I wonder if are there some good practices to keep html code short, and I mean the case when you have so much props/attributes, and I'm not thinking in backend at all or haml, just pure HTML.

Is there some good practice for these cases?

Comment: You can do a new line in the html tag, as in you can put each attribute in a new line. This will make your code really long, some people find it hard to read this way and some people find it hard to read when everything is in one line. So decide for yourself

Comment: that is exactly my dilemma, and it  doesn't seem to be a general or popular rule for this. I hate line more that 100 character, but of course in pure html if you solve with a new line for each properties the problem turn to be the opposite.

Comment: This comes down to opinion/preference, whatever way you prefer to do it is ok. There is no right or wrong with this. You can combine the 2 methods like put attribute in a new line when the line gets too long or say have 2-3 attribute on each line. Whatever way you like it better then do it that way. If there are other devs working on these files then you should have a short meeting with them to figure out the best approach for you

Answer (score 5):

I generally put each attribute on its own line in cases like this.

```
<div id="myId"
     class="class1 class2 class3"
     data-foo="yadda yaddd"
     data-bar="more yadda yadda">
     ...
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @ray I was thinkning the same, but if there are too many properties, the problems turn into another problem, but I rather this solution so far